# how to add reactstrap carousel as child component directly or using async?

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I'm using reactstrap in an application, but found some problem with react. The

```
import CarouselExample from './Sliders/CarouselExample';

   render() {

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div id="container">
                <CarouselExample />
            </div>

      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

line reports a problem and I have no idea with it since I'm a newbie with react-redux. What should I do in my code?

I've grabbed the example code for a carousel from here: https://reactstrap.github.io/components/carousel/

Application built with 16.9.0", "react-dom": "^16.9.0", "react-redux": "^7.1.0",   "reactstrap": "^8.0.1","redux": "^4.0.4" and "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0".

The container uses the react component, which is just repeating an image slider div.

Output:
[image]

I tried to follow guides and looked up example implementations but could not solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the bootstrap 4 dependency and CSS.

Install bootstrap 4.3 dependency and `import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"` in your index.js file.

Please see the sandbox for more details:
https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-newton-vty2r

Also beware of using `id` tags in `JSX`. It may cause issues when reusing a component. I prefer using `refs`. Hope this helps.

Comment: What is the meaning of refs?

Comment: here is an article that can help: https://www.javascriptstuff.com/use-refs-not-ids/